# How to create a Login task in OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How to create a task with OnClickListener???

I Tryed with two methods (AsyncTask & Runnable/Thread):

I have test the AsyncTask Method:

```
package de.CodingDev.game;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //Init Buttons

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }



        try{
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("music_menu.mp3");
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            player.prepare();
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.start();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

            Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new LoginTask(getActivity()).execute("http://auth.cddata.de/?username=" + URLEncoder.encode("") + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(""));
                }

            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }

}

class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {
    private FragmentActivity activity;

    public LoginTask(FragmentActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{
            URL oracle = new URL(urls[0]);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
            Toast.makeText(activity, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            in.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return (long) 0;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        //setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        //showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }

}
```

and i have tested a Runnable Method

```
package de.CodingDev.game;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //Init Buttons

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }



        try{
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("music_menu.mp3");
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            player.prepare();
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.start();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

            Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Runnable run = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try{
                                URL oracle = new URL("http://auth.cddata.de/?username=" + URLEncoder.encode("") + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(""));
                                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                in.close();
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    Thread t = new Thread(run);
                    t.start();
                }

            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

but this two Methods dosent works.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed, that you called `Toast.makeText(...).show()` from `doInBackground()`. It will not work. I wish I could write this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation...
Also, `URLEncoder.encode()` is deprecated. Try `encode` with encoding as the second argument.
And in the end, usually, network operations are implemented using `HttpUrlConnection` or `DefaultHttpClient` (the first is preferable). [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) you can find a code snippet.